# What are some good web resources for designing/building bunk bed?

Tags: woodworking, bedroom

I am looking to make bunk beds for a new house we are moving into.  Does anyone have any thoughts on a place to get some good plans?  Looking online has scared me and they all look like a scam.  Just looking for book recommendations or a website that someone knows is reputable.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use Google.  Tried "DIY Bunk bed plans"  " Bunk Bed plans" "Book Bunk bed plans"  ana-white.com seems ok.

Comment: [diy.stackexchange.com](http://diy.stackexchange.com/) is a great resource for asking questions about how to build a bunk bed, not so good for asking for other web resources.  That's like asking a contractor for the number of a competitor.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the image search first, then drill down to the site if you like the design.

Here's a plain jane variety from [HowToSpecialist.com](http://www.howtospecialist.com/finishes/furniture/how-to-build-a-bunk-bed/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried several google searches.

**1)** free bunk bed plans

**2)** bunk bed plans **site:.org**

**3)** bunk bed plans **site:.edu**

**4)** bunk bed plans **filetype:pdf**

Interestingly, it seems universities have information for students who want to build bunk beds in their dorm rooms